# What are the advantages of the gradle deamon if the build cache is disabled by default

Tags: maven, caching, gradle

I was going though the documentation on gradle and I was looking at possible issues it could cause when I found this. [7.5.5. What can go wrong with Daemon?](https://docs.gradle.org/4.3.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html)

This statement stood out most of all:

> It is also possible to destabilize the Daemon (and build environment in general) by running builds that do not release resources correctly. This is a particularly poignant problem when using Microsoft Windows as it is less forgiving of programs that fail to close files after reading or writing.

Then I seen [By default, the build cache is not enabled.](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_cache.html) which is very conflicting to the following statement:

> The Daemon is a long-lived process, so not only are we able to avoid the cost of JVM startup for every build, but we are able to cache information about project structure, files, tasks, and more in memory.

Found here: [7.1. Why the Gradle Daemon is important for performance](https://docs.gradle.org/4.3.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html)

I later ran `gradle build --scan` and confirmed the cache was in fact disabled. In fact the only deamon switch enabled was deamon.

So as I understand it, what makes gradle, as a build tool faster, is its ability to cache prior builds, but it is disabled by default, therefore it is really just like `mvn clean install -DskipTests` in regards to build performance unless caching is enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your quote:

> The Daemon is a long-lived process, so not only are we able to avoid the cost of JVM startup for every build, but we are able to cache information about project structure, files, tasks, and more in memory.

pretty much answers your question. That's talking about *metadata*, rather than the caching of actual built file contents. It still helps quite a bit with speed when repeatedly building a project to test small changes.