# Why Should I Disable Daemon In Gradle?

Tags: gradle

I see on some projects/some dockerfiles like `gradle build --no-daemon` and I don't understand it why I should disable daemon. Is there any disadvantage of daemons? I saw advantages of it in [What are the advantages of the gradle deamon if the build cache is disabled by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48148147/what-are-the-advantages-of-the-gradle-deamon-if-the-build-cache-is-disabled-by-d)

Comment: One simple reason: you don't want to leave an additional process running. If you're not using Gradle again any time soon, there's no benefit to the daemon.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR

**You should not disable Gradle daemon**. People put all kinds of flags and arguments not knowing what they actually accomplish and it only leads to misinformation and confusion.

For several years Gradle daemon is stable, enabled by default and Gradle own documentation section on it [recommends](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_daemon.html#continuous_integration) using it for both developer machines and CI/CD.

Flag `--no-daemon` doesn't prevent Gradle daemon from spawning, it just pkills the process after the build is over. In containerised environment that kills all processes at the end it just makes no difference whether you provide the option or not.